# How can I see unavailable servers in Nginx logs?

Tags: logging, nginx, health-monitoring

Where in the Nginx logs will it say that a server is unavailable because it failed `x` times in `y` seconds?

I have a set of servers in an upstream block in nginx, each one has a `fail_timeout` and `max_fails` value set like so:

```
upstream loadbalancer {
    server ip1:80 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=60s;
    server ip2:80 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=60s;
}
```

If I intentionally bring down one of these servers (let's say ip:80), NGINX gets back a `503` which I have marked as an invalid header. So I make sure NGINX hits that server three times in sixty seconds.

I expect there to be something in the logs that the server is being marked as unavailable, i.e. that the `fail_timeout` has kicked in. But I can't find anything.

Here is my logging config:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  main; 
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a log message when the server has exceeded max_fails.
It has been added in 1.9.1.
Log level is warning, the message says "upstream server temporarily disabled".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can get logs of unavailable servers. But you can for example execute the **lsof** command to get additional list log files of your **httpd root** by its PID.

1) First xecute this command to get the PID of you HTTPD root:

```
  > ps axu |grep httpd
```

2) Then Copy the PID of **root**. Lets say the PID is **1234**.

3) Next we use the PID **1234** and execute the final command in order to to get the log files of the httpd **root**:

```
  > lsof -p 1234 |grep log
```

This has really helped me a lot finding missing logs. Now you can then check if the log files contains anything regarding **unavailable servers**. Best of Luck

Comment: Thanks -- but I am not seeing any logs when I do this -- running nginx in a docker container so I imagine that might by muddying the waters. It's a cool idea though -- will try if I run nginx elsewhere

Comment: Thank you. Best of Luck Mate!

Answer (score 1):

You should see logging in the error log with useful information on the reason. Here are some examples from Nginx 1.8

```
 [error] 9369#0: *837 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

 [error] 9369#0: *851 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream

 [error] 9369#0: *844 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream
```

As you can see, the log level is `error` so that is not an issue in your config.

You mention setting a 503 header to mark hosts as unavailable. This will not be detected in the default Nginx settings. To use specific response codes to determine upstream host status look into the [proxy_next_upstream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream) option.

Setting it to the following would include 503 response codes in the list of results that counts as an upstream failure:

```
proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_503;
```

> From the documentation:
>   The directive also defines what is considered an unsuccessful attempt of communication with a server. The cases of error, timeout and invalid_header are always considered unsuccessful attempts, even if they are not specified in the directive. The cases of http_500, http_502, http_503 and http_504 are considered unsuccessful attempts only if they are specified in the directive. The cases of http_403 and http_404 are never considered unsuccessful attempts

Comment: So I have this directive in my config and I can see these errors in my log, including the server the request failed on. However, I want a definitive record in the log that says this server is being avoided for the `fail_timeout` time -- instead of having to parse the logs and come up with some logic for which servers are being avoided because they failed a `max_fails` number of times. I don't care if the servers sometimes get `502` and `503` and `504` (that's expected in the system I'm working on), I just care if it happens often enough to trigger the server avoidance in Nginx.

Comment: Yes it's pretty stupid, but they don't seem to offer this :(  Perhaps one of the logging levels less than error would include it (along with a bunch of other junk! )